# Show javascript variable in html div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Once a form is submitted my javascript hides one div and shows another:

```
function deviceReady() {
    console.log("deviceReady");
    $("#loginPage").on("pageinit",function() {
        console.log("pageinit run");
        $("#loginForm").on("submit",handleLogin);
        checkPreAuth();
    });
    $.mobile.changePage("#loginTest");
    $('#loginTest').html('Hello World!');
}
```

The bottom line is where I'm trying to add some text to the div that is dynamically displayed. However, nothing is displayed in the div. I'd also like to show the variable from another function in the same file.

it's the `var e = $("#username").val();` from the code below which I would like to add to the div eventually.

```
function init() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceReady, true);
    delete init;
}

function checkPreAuth() {
    console.log("checkPreAuth");
    var form = $("#loginForm");
    if(window.localStorage["username"] != undefined && window.localStorage["password"] != undefined) {
        $("#username", form).val(window.localStorage["username"]);
        $("#password", form).val(window.localStorage["password"]);
        handleLogin();
    }
}

function handleLogin() {
    var e = $("#username").val();
    var p = $("#password").val();

    if(e != "" && p != "") {
        $.ajax({ 
                 type: 'POST', 
                 url: 'http://localhost/php/log.php', 
                 crossDomain: true,
                 data:  {username: e, password :p},
                 dataType: 'json', 
                 async: false,

                 success: function (response){ 
                    if (response.success) { 
                        $.mobile.changePage("#loginTest");
                     } 
                    else {
                        alert("Your login failed");
                    }
                 },
                 error: function(error){
                    alert('Could not connect to the database' + error);
                 }
               }); 
    }
    else {
        alert("You must enter username and password");
    }
    return false;
}

function deviceReady() {
    console.log("deviceReady");
    $("#loginPage").on("pageinit",function() {
        console.log("pageinit run");
        $("#loginForm").on("submit",handleLogin);
        checkPreAuth();
    });
    $.mobile.changePage("#loginTest");
    $('#loginTest').html('Hello World!');
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<body>
<div id="loginPage" data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Auth Demo</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" placeholder="Username" />
  </div>
  <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password" />
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="Login" id="submitButton" onclick="handleLogin()">
  <div data-role="footer">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="loginTest" data-role="page">
<div id="name">
</div>
</div>


</body>
```

Comment: and your HTML markup? better a jsfiddle.net

Comment: Your HTML would be helpful in answering this question.

Comment: We need your entire JavaScript code, I suspect your function deviceReady is not running

Comment: I've updated it with all of my javascript

Answer (score 0):

try this on element id loginTest (#loginTest)

```
document.getElementById('loginTest').innerHTML= your variable here; //or any string
```

if you are using jquery

```
$( '#loginTest' ).text( your variable ); //or any string
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you be better to restrict the post back:

```
<input type="button" value="Login" id="submitButton" onClientClick="handleLogin()">
```

and then return false from the function.